# Any software to block all calls and all SMSes allowing only 3G internet?

Tags: internet, call-screening, dual-sim, sms-blocking

My dad gave his other dual-sim card to me, which has internet service that he does not need. I do not want to get his calls or SMSes, I only want to use his internet.

I have tried to do this unsuccessfully with Mobile Manager. I selected the option to block all calls and SMSes with the software, but I can see missed call notifications. I do not want to see them at the top bar. The internet connection works nevertheless.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't it be easier to just change the contract on the SIM card to a data-only contract and let the phone company do all the blocking for you? It would also save you paying for services you're not using.